# oracle sql procedures that will give results in grid

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure that will give me results in grid form (if it's possible).

actually, it's a normal query with 3-5 parameters but i want to do it inside a procedure (i will use it for the program i'm making)

i know how to create simple procedures but those will only give me one line output.
something like this:

```
---run procedure

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

begin
  procedure_name(param1);
end;

---procedure output

anonymous block completed

sample procedure_name output
```

Comment: No such luck in Oracle.  You need to use `dbms_output.put_line()` (or something similar) to get output.  If you want to print the results from a query, then you need to loop over the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  this dbms_output.put_line() will only show a single result, or can it also show multiple results? also, thank you for editing my question, i must learn how to do that.

Comment: @itsmePJ Did you mean that you would like to have multiple rows to be returned when the procedure is executed?

Comment: @user75ponic yes. upon searching/googling i found this: REFCURSOR ... or if there is other way? I'm a MS SQL person, this is my first time to create procedures in Oracle

Comment: @itsmePJ That's exactly I was about to propose or suggest. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @user75ponic thank you! will try to do it first and I will definitely ask you if it fails. thanks again!

Comment: @itsmePJ You are welcome bro, by the way, use SYS_REFCURSOR.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 12c this can be achieved using `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`:

```
create or replace procedure get_data
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;  
  c2 SYS_REFCURSOR;  
BEGIN
  OPEN c1 FOR 
  select 'First result' as what, 1 as some_number from dual;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c1);

  OPEN c2 FOR 
  select 'Second result' as what, 2 as second_column, 3 as third_column 
  from dual;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c2);

END;
/
```

Then run it:

```
exec get_data;
```

And e.g. SQL*Plus will display this:

```
SQL> exec get_data;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1

WHAT         SOME_NUMBER
------------ -----------
First result           1

1 row selected.

ResultSet #2

WHAT          SECOND_COLUMN THIRD_COLUMN
------------- ------------- ------------
Second result             2            3

1 row selected.

SQL>
```

Other SQL clients might display the results in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

-- Simple procedure to return cursor as output parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_out_cur (OUT_RES OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN OUT_RES FOR SELECT 22 FROM DUAL;
END;
-- Call procedure from anonymous block using bind var for the
-- cursor output. When prompted by Toad choose CURSOR as the
-- variable's datatype.
BEGIN
    proc_out_cur (:res);
END;
```